# Populate field value with other field value if 0

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to populate a field value (value1) with another fields value (value2) if field value1 is 0. This is what I have so far:

```
jQuery(function() {
var value1 = $('#input_41_49').val();
var value2 = $('#input_41_77').val();

if (jQuery(value1).val() == 0){
jQuery(value2).val(value1);
}
});
```

How do I do this when the field value changes?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:You are reading value in `value1` and `value2` and again calling `.val()`, instead store jquery object for `value1` and `value2` and then call `.val()`. Also use `parseInt()` (or `parseFloat()` if float values) to compare it with `0`.

```
jQuery(function() {
   var value1 = $('#input_41_49');
   var value2 = $('#input_41_77');

  if (parseInt(jQuery(value1).val()) == 0){
    jQuery(value2).val(value1);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

using too much jQuery, change to:

```
jQuery(function() {
    var value1 = jQuery('#input_41_49');
    var value2 = jQuery('#input_41_77');

    if (parseInt(value1.val(), 10) == 0){
        value1.val(value2.val());
    }
});
```

For change event you could use :

```
$("#value2").on("input",function(e){
    var $thisVal = $(this).val(),
        $value1 = $("#value1");
    if( parseInt(value1.val(), 10) == 10 ) {
        value1.val($thisVal);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, so I'm using:

jQuery(function() {
    var value1 = jQuery('#input_41_49');
    var value2 = jQuery('#input_41_77');

    if (parseInt(value1.val(), 10) == 0){
        value1.val(value2.val());
    }
});

<input type="text" id="#input_41_49" value="">
<input type="text" id="#input_41_77" value="3">

But is not working, how do I use the change event so if the value of 1 = 0, change to value 2?

Comment: Bind to the change event - see my answer above.

Comment: @sideroxylon you could use on('input' … ) event to check for change event, as in my added answer

Answer (score 0):

You want to use function overload of `val`

```
var value2 = jQuery('#input_41_77');
$('#input_41_49').val(function(_,prevVal){
    return prevVal == "0" ? value2 : prevVal; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 jQuery(function() {
    var value1 = $('#input_41_49');
    var value2 = $('#input_41_77');

    if ($.trim(value1.val()) == 0){
      value2.val(value1);
    } 
});
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question?

Answer (score 0):

Get and compare values when Value1 changes:

```
$('#input_41_49').change(function() {
        var value1 = $('#input_41_49').val();
        var value2 = $('#input_41_77').val();

        if (value1 == 0){
         $('#input_41_47').val(value2);
        } 
    });
```

Fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/jzf2r8kh/)

Answer (score 0):

Following code does

- changes the value of input1 with input2 if input1 is empty.
- If input1 is manually edited and input1 contains some value, input2 changes won't be reflected in input1.

  ```
  // assign the initial value1 var to value of input1
  var init_value1 = $('#value1').val();

  // if input 2 value changes: listen to input2 for cut, paste, keyup and change event 
  $('#value2').on('cut paste keyup change', function(){
      // if input1 initial value is empty assign input1 value to input2 value
       if(init_value1=== ''){
          $('#value1').val($('#value2').val());
       }
  });

  // if input1 value changes: in case input1 is edited, listen to cut, paste, keyup, change
  $('#value1').on('cut paste keyup change', function(){
      // assign input1 value to initial value1 variable
      init_value1 = $('#value1').val();
  });
  ```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sameer_kc/7t03tpbu/1/)

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are discouraged, because they don't teach the solution.